# jquery loop to check if element is empty

Tags: jquery, loops

```
<div class="parent">

 <div class="child_1">

  content to remove if child_2 is empty!

 </div>

 <div class="child_2">

  content of child_2

 </div>
```

in the page repeated a dozen times..how could i check if any "child_2" element is empty and if so remove content of "child_1"??

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('div.child_2:empty').each(function() {
  $(this).prev('div.child_1').empty();
});
```

Comment: Beware `:empty` is only true for "no children whatsoever", not for elements with "whitespace-only" content.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
$('.child_2').each(function(){

  if($(this).html()==''){
    $(this).prev('.child_1').html('');
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with `$.each()`?

```
$(".child_1").each(function() {
    var child_2 = $(this).siblings(".child_2"); // "this" is the element being iterated over
    if (child_2.html().length == 0) {
        $(this).html("");
    }
}
```

I think that is what you want.